# How can I apply a predicate to one array and use the result to obtain values from another in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 arrays (they are actually 2 dimensional but I don't think that is important for the question)

```
val arr1 = arrayOf<Char>('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b')
val arr2 = arrayOf<Char>('z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u')
```

I'm trying to implement the following method

```
fun filter(predicate: (T?) -> Boolean): Collection<Char> { ... }
```

The arrays above are simplified as contents of arr1 in the real code is a nullable generic (T?) but I'm guessing we can carry on like this for the question.

So what I am trying to do is apply the predicate to the first array and get the  values from the corresponding indices from the 2nd.

So lets say I try

```
val res = obj.filter { it == 'b' }
```

I would want to get a collection with 'y' and 'u' in it.

I've been going around the houses on this so I think I've missed the proper way.  My last attempt was along the lines of (used flatten as it's a 2 dimensional array)

```
val newList = arr1.flatten().mapIndexed{idx, it -> predicate}
```

I could then use this to get the values from arr2 (assuming they always flatten consistently ?)

My question I guess is either

a) how do I get a list of the indexes using mapIndexed with the predicate
or 
b) what is the better way to do it (I'm assuming I've taken the wrong approach tbh)

Comment: Looks like an application for a [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html) i.e. store key-value pairs instead of handling array-indexes. Otherwise your approach looks viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val result = (arr1 zip arr2)
    .filter { (c1, _) -> predicate(c1) }
    .map { (_, c2) -> c2 }
```

Comment: That's fantastic thanks.  I remember seeing the zip function a few days ago and thinking how useful it looked in the right circumstances.  Obviously in one ear and out the other...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zip the lists and use extension

```
fun <Any> List<Pair<Any,Any>>.myfilter(c: Any): List<Any>{
    val result: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()
    for(item in this){
        if(item.first == c)
            result.add(item.second)
    }
    return result
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val arr1 = arrayOf<Char>('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b')
    val arr2 = arrayOf<Char>('z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u')

    val zipped: List<Pair<Char,Char>> = arr1 zip arr2

    print(zipped.myfilter('e'))
}
```